# How To Add Result From Method To The Result of SQL From Php Array - JSON

Tags: php, android, json

I'm working in `loginModel.php`. And extracting it's results, in the mean time encoding the image to `base64` to pass the result to `JSON` with the user info.

The decoding for the image will be in `Android App` and I was trying to put/attach the `encodedString` (locating the image - path and name) result that come from different method to `$result`

(The sql query only return info that was `SELECT` ).

Here's my php file:

```
$result = mysqli_query($this->db->connect,$sql_login); 

           //CHECK RESULT
                $rowCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                if ($rowCheck > 0) {
                    $result             = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                    $profPath           = $result['PicturePath'];
                    $profName           = $result['ProfilePicture'];
                    $salt               = $result['SaltPassword'];
                    $encrypted_password = $result['Password'];
                    //ENCODED STRING
                    $encodedString = $this->encodeProfBaseString($profName,$profPath);
                    $result['encodedString'] = $result['$encodedString'];

                    //CALL checkHashSaltSHA METHOD
                    $hash = $this->checkHashSaltSHA($salt,$userPassword);

                    //CHECK PASSWORD
                    if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
                            return $result;
                    }
                    else{
                        return FALSE;
                    }        
                }
```

**All I want is to make `encodedString` will be return as well, as a part of `$result`.** How can I insert the result from array `$result`?

[image: encode]

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you just need to replace

`$result['encodedString'] = $result['$encodedString'];`

with

`$result['encodedString'] = $encodedString;`

Comment: This from my loginController - $response["encodedString"]   = $result["encodedString"];       

                                echo json_encode($response);

Comment: `$result['encodedString'] = $result['$encodedString'];` has no effect anyway. I think you should leave it as I suggested above and look at what `$this->encodeProfBaseString($profName,$profPath)` returns. It must be returning a " ", so this what you need to fix